# How do I connect Dreamweaver to a MySQL Database?

Tags: mysql, dreamweaver

I've been trying to connect Dreamweaver to a MySQL Database for a while.

These are the login data:

```
$mysql_host = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a7426xxx_xxxxx";
$mysql_user = "a7426xxx_xxxxx";
$mysql_password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
```

I click dynamic text in DW, then create a recordset. Then define connection. Then New. Then I enter the data.

Connection name: I just give it a random name.
MySQL server: I fill in the $mysql_host data above.
User name: I fill in the $mysql_user name above.
Password: I fill in the $mysql_password above.

Then I click select database but DW can't find the database. It just says an unidentified error has occured.

Help please.

Kind regards

Pongy

Comment: Does your webhost allow connections to their MySQL instances from remote hosts? Most don't, you'll probably have to use [SSH tunnelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) if you really need Dreamweaver to talk directly to the database.

Comment: Your question is similar like how to connect Notepad with MySQL... Where is the file hosted? On your computer or on server? Maybe SQL server is refusing outside connections.

Comment: @webarto - in fairness to @Pongy, Dreamweaver _will_ allow you to connect to a MySQL database directly, but in the scenario of editing files to be put on a remote web host, it's almost never going to be work because the database server wont' be externally available. This tends not to be immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an obvious answer but, double check that you have not only entered the correct information in the Connections files, but that you have also setup a "testing server" in your site definition in addition to your "remote server".  The settings should be the same, but without defining this, DW won't be able to actually do any of the dynamic stuff in the editor.

Here's the Adobe answer to your question:
http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/165/tn_16575.html -> Setting up the PHP / MySQL Site Definition in Dreamweaver

Answer (score -3):

@Raz
 install https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/
 and try entering in your credentials below

```
$mysql_host = "mysql16.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a7426xxx_xxxxx";
$mysql_user = "a7426xxx_xxxxx";
$mysql_password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
```

if that doesn't work, call your hosting company and ask them why that's not working. if you have access to the `my.cnf` file on your server follow the instruction below to allow your mysql sever to accept remote connection.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Once you allow mysql remote connection, you can login into mysql from dreamweaver console.

most likely that you can't connect has to do with your local ip address. mysql isn't allowing remote connection. you need to enable it.

Comment: "Install Workbench" sounds like the wrong way if the OP wants to use Dreamweaver